# How to get HashMap id value in ListView onItemClick?

Tags: android, android-listview

I tried to add ImageList to my application. i added it successfully. It shows Logos of banks which i was selected. I added that through **HashMap**, because i want to take bank name when click the log image.

But i can't get the bank name in **onItemClick** method. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

This is my Activity code.

```
public void getImageData() {

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson1);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("bank");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            img_url = jsonChildNode.optString("logo");
            String test1 = img_test_url + img_url;
            bName = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
            map.put(bName, test1);

        }

        ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),map);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Error...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HashMap<String, String> obj = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(arg2);
            String name = (String) obj.get("bName");
            Log.d("Bank Name", name);

        }
    });
}
```

This is my Adapter class

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    ImageView imageView;
    private String[] mKeys;
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    ItemsAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, String> map) {

        this.context = context;
        this.map = map;
        mKeys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return map.get(mKeys[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String key = mKeys[position];
        String Value = getItem(position).toString();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = convertView;
            if (null == convertView)
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
            imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            URL imageURL = null;


            Log.d("value", Value);
            Log.d("key", key);
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(Value);
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);// Convert to bitmap
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return rowView ;
        }
}
```

This is LogCat error.

```
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at com.example.testhashimage.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:161)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-17 13:58:13.620: E/AndroidRuntime(10172):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your application should crash when you press on the item on the ListView, or what?

Comment: @blackbelt sorry for that. i forgot to upload logcat.now i updated it.

Comment: @anuruddhika what is line 161?

Comment: @Raghunandan HashMap<String, String> obj = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(arg2); this is that line.

Comment: @anuruddhika NPE is bcoz adapter is not initialized

Comment: @Raghunandan i initialized it in getImageData() method ne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors. First you are trying to access a member class that is not intialized, since  you are hding  the member's class  scoping redeclaring the variable with local scope. This is easily fixable. You can use

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
```

the firs argument of onItemClick to retrieve the element at position. In your case it is:

```
 arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)
```

the second error is that you are casting a `String` to `HashMap`. Your `getItem` returns:

```
map.get(mKeys[position]);
```

and since you declared  `HashMap<String, String>` in your custom adapter, `getItem` is actually return a String instance. So you have the wrong cast. As soon as you fix the NPE you will get a `ClassCastException`

Edit: to achieve what you want you should change from

1. Switch form HashMap to another kind, index, order based collection. It could be, for instance an `ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>`, or you can create your own `javabean`. I will assume that you are going to use the `Pair` class, with the id as first element, and the url as second value
2. Change `getView` and `getItem` accordingly.  You can get rid

   ```
   String key = mKeys[position];
   String Value = getItem(position).toString();
   ```

your getItem will look like:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataset.get(position);
}
```

and getView will start with

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Pair<String, String> item = (Pair<String, String>)getItem(position);
        String Value = item.second;
    }
```

inside onItemClick you'll get a similar thing:

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
       Pair<String, String> item = (Pair<String, String>)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
       String id = item.first;
    }
```

as correctly pointed out by @Raghunandan, you should all the Network/Blocking related operations into a different thread. The mostly easy way, android friendly, is to use an AsyncTask. You can read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html) guide.

Comment: I did not get it ne. :(

Comment: what did you not get? Could you be more specific?

Comment: i did not understand,"what should i do for this problem"

Comment: to fix the `NPE` use the first argument of `onItemClick`

Comment: @ blackbelt Ok. i got it. but it display the image URL. i want to get the Id of hashMap. it is the bank name.

Comment: @blackbelt could also suggest to get rid of n/w operation in `getView`

Comment: @blackbelt should i add Pair<String, String> to getImageData() method instead of hashMap?

Comment: an ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>, but yes yo need it

Comment: @blackbelt why i can't use HashMap? :(

Comment: the question is why do you want to use an HashMap?

Comment: @blackbelt what is this dataset.get(position)?

Comment: dataset is the name of the ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Bank object that as a name and a logo as attributes and then pass an ArrayList of bank objects to your adapter.